# Is this condition equivalent to being differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Consider a function $f : U \subset \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ and the following two assertions:

- $f$ is differentiable at $p \in U$, i.e., there exists a linear map $df_p : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that

  $$\lim_{v \to 0} \frac {f(p + v) - f(p) - df_p(v)} {\Vert v \Vert} = 0$$
- $f$ is continuous at $p$, and there exists a linear map $df_p : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that

  $$df_p(v) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac {f(p + tv) - f(p)} t$$

Clearly, the first assertion implies the second. Does the converse also hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ defined by

$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\
0 & (x,y) =(0,0)
\end{cases}$$

is a counterexample. It is [Gâteaux differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative?wprov=sfti1), its Gâteaux derivative at the origin is the vanishing map and is therefore linear.

However $f$ is not [Fréchet differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative?wprov=sfti1) at $(0,0)$. If it was, its Fréchet derivative would be equal to zero at the origin. However

$$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{f(t,t^2)}{\sqrt{t^2+t^4}} \neq 0$$

A contradiction.